# How do I check conditions & based on the output I would like to move to a specific cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula which will be able to check a condition? so IF the formula detects a specific word like 'ab' it should select a value from next cell:

[image]

Example above will check if text is equal to 'ab', if the condition is true then select a value from column C else select value from column B. In the example A1 equals 'aa' so the formula will return 1 from column B, A2 equals 'vv' so the formula will retune 1 from column B ………….A4 is equals to 'ab' so this time the formula will return 0 which is in column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(A1="ab",C1,B1)
```

Comment: Can you answer another question of my, how do I write a IF function that checks each line for example if A1="ab" select B1:D1 else if A2="ab" select B2:D2 else if A3="ab" select B3:D3 etc….